# Drush one line command to create field

Tags: 7, drush

I want to create field with name `img` for content type `announcement`

From the documentation, I can type `drush field-create announcement`. After that typing the field name `img`, after that type `2`, lastly type `1`.

Is there any ways achieving this through one line command?

Answer (score 5):

just type :
    drush field-create announcement img,image,image_image

the last two are field_type,widget_name